# How to set the bias_term false in a convolutional layer pycaffe?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using pycaffe to create my net and I want to set the bias term in a convolutional layer to false, but can not find anything how to do so. My code-snippet so far:

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers als L, params as P

n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data,kernel_size = 3,stride = 1,num_output=16,pad=1,weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mention, this is done by setting the `bias_term` parameter to `false`.
In general, you can find most layers and their parameters documented in the [Layer Catalogue](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html). You can set any parameter from PyCaffe by simply using the documented names and values from the Layer catalogue. Just remember, that you have to use correct Python syntax, i.e. `False` and not `false`!

```
n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data,
                        kernel_size=3,
                        stride=1,
                        num_output=16,
                        pad=1,
                        weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'),
                        bias_term=False
                        )
```

This will create the following entry in the `.prototxt` file:

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    bias_term: false
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the option is recognized correctly and put inside the `convolution_param` block.

Comment: Thank you, I have known about the catalogue but it'd be very helpful if there  is some kind of pycaffe documentation

Comment: I know, I struggled with the lack of pycaffe documentation for a long time. Now, I just look at the pycaffe and caffe code quite often. It is written quite understandable, so I rather rely on the code than some outdated blog posts. But I agree, good docs would be *very* helpful.